# When an integral with respect to a Poisson point process is finite?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $N(ds,dv)$ be a Poisson measure on $\mathbb{R} _+ \times \mathbb{R} _+$ with intensity $dsdv$. Let $N = \sum\limits \delta_{(s_i,v_i)}$. Assume that $N$ is compatible with a filtration $\{ \mathscr{F} _t \}$; that is, $N ([0;t] \times V)$ is $\mathscr{F} _t$-measurable for any Borel $V \subset \mathbb{R} _+$, and $N((t,t+s] \times V)$ is independent of $\mathscr{F} _t$. Let $a(s, \omega)$ be a predictable non-negative right-continuous process. Consider the integral
$$
X(t) = \int\limits _{(0;t]\times \mathbb{R}_+} 
I_{[0;a(s)]}(v) N(ds,dv) = \sum\limits _{0<s_i \leq t}\delta_{(s_i,v_i)}I_{[0;a(s_i)]}(v_i).
$$

Fix $T >0$. Is it true that

$$
\{\int _0 ^T a(s) ds < \infty  \} = \{ X(T) < \infty \} \quad   a.s.?
$$

Now, if $ E \int _0 ^T a(s) ds < \infty$, then $X(t)$ is finite a.s. and $X(t) - \int _0 ^t a(s) ds$ is an $\{ \mathscr{F} _t \}$-martingale. Somewhat similar question was considered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13577/non-existence-of-integral-with-respect-to-poisson-random-measure), although the integrand is deterministic there. The question I ask may have been discussed somewhere, so I would appreciate the reference.

**Addition**. The answer to the question is certainly negative if $a$ is not supposed to be predictable. Indeed, let $\gamma _k =  \min \{v : N([1-\frac{1}{2^{k-1}};1-\frac{1}{2^{k}}) \times [0;v] ) > 0 \}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and

$$
a(s) = \frac 12 \gamma _k, \ \ \ s \in [1-\frac{1}{2^{k-1}};1-\frac{1}{2^{k}}).
$$

Then $X(1) \equiv 0$ a.s., but 
$$
\int _0 ^1 a(s) ds = \frac 12 \sum _k \frac{\gamma _k}{E\gamma _k} = \infty
$$
a.s., since $\gamma _k$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\frac{1}{2^{k}}$, $E\gamma _k = 2^{k}$, and $(\gamma _k)$ is a sequence of independent r.v. However, I don't think such trick can work with the predictability assumptions.

Comment: Surely this can't work? Here's an approach that I will try to work out the details of: Let $Z$ be a random variable taking values in the integers. If $Z=k$, then construct a continuous function in a systematic way so that the region below the curve does not contain any of the Poisson points. The function should be p'wise linear on intervals of width $1/k$. An approx version of this (failing predictability for now) is to define $a(s)$ to be the minimum height of a Poisson point with $x$ coordinate in the interval $[i/k,(i+1)/k)$ containing $s$. The expected value of $a(s)$ is $k$ for each $s$.

Comment: So am I right that predictability is satisfied if $a(s)$ is a.s. continuous? If so, choose an independent $Z$ first. Then do a continuous version of your construction (piecewise linear segments with fixed, but very large slope ($2^{2^k}$?) that works up to $1-2^{-k}$.

Comment: @Anthony Quas a continuous function does not have to be predictable. The construction you propose would lead to a process which is not predictable. I actually believe that the answer to the question in the post is positive.

Comment: What is the definition of predictable?

Comment: @ Anthony Quas measurable with respect to the smallets $\sigma$ algebra generated by left-continuous adapted processes.

Comment: So I think I may have been misled by wikipedia, where it says that any left continuous process is predictable. Maybe it should have said any left continuous *adapted* process is predictable.